# Bootstrap for ASP Populate table from txt file

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

I've been trying to populate a table made using Bootstrap for ASP from a txt file but it seems I keep getting stuck on doing it...
I'll leave below my attempt so you can take a look at it and perhaps help me out.
The format used in the txt file is the following:

```
Column1Txt Column2Txt Column3Txt Column4Txt
Column1Txt Column2Txt Column3Txt Column4Txt
Column1Txt Column2Txt Column3Txt Column4Txt
Column1Txt Column2Txt Column3Txt Column4Txt
```

Here's my attempt of doing it:

```
<div class="container">
            <div class="left">
                <div class="row">
                    <table class="table table-striped">
                        <!-- table head -->
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>#</th>
                                <th>Column1</th>
                                <th>Column2</th>
                                <th>Column3</th>
                                <th>Column4</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                    </table>
                    <iframe src="/tablecontent/content.txt" frameborder="0"></iframe>
            </div>
        </div>
   </div>
```

I know it's not even inside the table but I've also tried to do it with it inside the table and it didn't work properly as well.

Thanks for your time in advance.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, you need to read in the contents of the text file and parse out the data. Looking at the sample, I'll assume space-delimited, but you'll have to decide that for yourself. There are countless ways to do that. Here's one:

Class or struct or hold data:

```
public class ColumnData()
{
    public string Column1 { get; set; }
    public string Column2 { get; set; }
    public string Column3 { get; set; }
    public string Column4 { get; set; }
}
```

Parsing logic:

```
string rawText = System.IO.File.ReadAllText("Full path to file");
string[] rows = rawText.Split(System.Environment.NewLine);
List<ColumnData> data = rows
    .Select(rowText => rowText.Split(" "))
    .Select(rowArray => new ColumnData
    {
        Column1 = rowArray[0],
        Column2 = rowArray[1],
        Column3 = rowArray[2],
        Column4 = rowArray[3]
    })
    .ToList();
```

Then, once you have the data in a usable format, you can create appropriate HTML. You could do that via a GridView, a Repeater, or even just some string manipulation to build the HTML manually. If you go for that last option, you'll need to add it to the page somehow, such as by adding a Literal control and populating it with your manually built string.

Here's an example using a manually build HTML string:

Literal control in markup:

```
<table class="table table-striped">
    <!-- table head -->
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>#</th>
                <th>Column1</th>
                <th>Column2</th>
                <th>Column3</th>
                <th>Column4</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <asp:Literal id="columnData" runat="server"/>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

Code to build string (using `data` from parsing logic):

```
string rowFormat = "<tr><td></td><td>{0}</td><td>{1}</td><td>{2}</td><td>{3}</td></tr>";
string[] rowStrings = data
    .Select(row => string.Format(rowFormat, row.Column1, row.Column2, row.Column3, row.Column4))
    .ToArray();
string html = string.Join(System.Environment.NewLine, rowStrings);

// Populate literal control
columnData.Value = html;
```

**Edit:** Big disclaimer: this is **proof of concept** type code only. Notice it has **no** error handling. I don't know that I'd use this at all; this is just to show you the general idea.

Comment: Awesome, just wanted to thank you for this simple implementation. However, I've found in .NET 4.6.1 that columnData.Value has to be replaced with columnData.Text